# Cocoa: Simulating Command+Tab in CGEvent

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, cgeventtap

I want to simulate `Application Switcher` in my app and I think CGEvent maybe can do that.

Well, after learning some basic information about CGEvent, I can simulate the key press `Command + Tab`. But the Application Switcher window just flashing by and switch to another app immediately.

I realize that I need to `hold` the Command key and press Tab key to choose the app. So, here's my code:

```
// Hold the Command key
let source = CGEventSourceCreate(.HIDSystemState)
let event = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, 55 as CGKeyCode, true)
CGEventSetIntegerValueField(event, .KeyboardEventAutorepeat, 1)
CGEventPost(.CGHIDEventTap, event)

// Press Tab key once
let source = CGEventSourceCreate(.HIDSystemState)
let keyDown = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, 48 as CGKeyCode, true)
CGEventSetFlags(keyDown, .MaskCommand)
CGEventPost(.CGHIDEventTap, keyDown)
let keyUp = CGEventCreateKeyboardEvent(source, 48 as CGKeyCode, false)
CGEventPost(.CGHIDEventTap, keyUp)
```

But it doesn't work! Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: When I type Command-tab manually, the Application Switcher window just flashes by and switches to another app immediately.

Comment: Why do you set KeyboardEventAutorepeat?

Comment: You have to simulate the user: Command down, tab down, tab up, command up.

Comment: @Willeke It doesn't matter whether I add the code `CGEventSetIntegerValueField(event, .KeyboardEventAutorepeat, 1)` or not

Comment: @Willeke Maybe my expression was not accurate. I find this discussion: [How do I script the Application Switcher?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1928648?start=0&tstart=0) exactly had the same problem with me.

Comment: Sorry I didn't know I had to hold the Command key. Try `CGEventSetFlags(keyUp, .MaskCommand)` before `CGEventPost(.CGHIDEventTap, keyUp)`.

Comment: @Willeke It works! Thanks man! I didn't realize that I also need to set flags when Key Up. Please answer this post and I will set it as the best answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Command flag is missing in the keyup event. Add `CGEventSetFlags(keyUp, .MaskCommand)` before `CGEventPost(.CGHIDEventTap, keyUp)`.

Comment: my apologies if this is poor from, but you seem to be expert in this area. I've just posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58673983/simulating-opt-or-other-modifiers-with-cgeventcreatekeyboardevent-cgeventse -- If you are able to offer any insight, I am most grateful!